# TypeError with the arguments of a class

Tags: python, constructor, typeerror

`TypeError: circle() takes no arguments`
with this code:

```
class circle:
    def _init_(self,r):
        self.r=self
    def diameter(self):
        return self.r*2
c=circle(7.0)
print("%f"%c)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: ```def __init__(self,r)``` there are 2 underscores

Answer (score 1):

A constructor is defined by the `__init__` method (with two underscores), not `_init_` like you have right now. Also note that you should probably be saving the passed `r`, not assigning `self.r = self`:

```py
class circle:
    def __init__(self,r):
        self.r = r
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some mistakes:

1. Python constructor has `__init__` 2 underscores.
2. It should be `%c.diameter()`. You need to call the function of the class. You cannot just pass the instantiated class

```
class circle:
    def __init__(self,r):
        self.r=r
    def diameter(self):
        return self.r*2
c=circle(7.0)
print("%f"%c.diameter())
```